# Can someone tell me why im unable to load Javascript files into separate html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Im currently making an electron application. i have an index.html file where ive loaded in Javascript files within the head tag. I am able to access the JS functions without any issues.

I've now created a separate browser window, and for this I've made another html file. When I attempt to load in another JavaScript file it doesn't allow me to access any of the functions. What's weird is that i can load in the CSS file no problem that works. Why is it so much hassle to load in a JS sheet, I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days now :/

I've also attempted to use module.exports in my sidebar.js file so that I can try and trigger the functions using the renderer.js file and the main.js file but it gives me an error saying "document has not been defined"

Can anyone think of a solution? its probably something simple but I'm honestly losing it here.

Comment: If you have a module in your code and are using the result of function for the others, you need to import those functions similar to this `import { export1 as alias1 } from "module-name";`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script tags at the end, right before the end body tag.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try adding `<script module src="sidebar.js"></script>`
2. Or may be you can check that the file name is proper sidebar.js. Just check it once!